# Convergence in topological spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

$x_{n}(t)=t^{2n}$ in $C[0;1]$

It is obvious to investigate convergence in space $C[0;1/2]$, but in $C[0;1]$ there is two limits of $x_{n}(t)$: in $[0;1)$ it is $0$ and at $\{1\}$ it is $1$

Should I say that the sequence doesn't converge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sequence doesn't converge uniformly. If it did, and if it converged to some $f\in C[0,1]$, then it would converge pointwise to $f$. But then we would have$$(\forall t\in[0,1]):f(t)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }t<1\\1&\text{ if }t=1.\end{cases}$$But $f\notin C[0,1]$. So, in $C[0,1]$ endowed with the topology of unform convergence, your series diverges.

You can also prove that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\sup\lvert f-f_n\rvert=1.$$This also proves that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge to $f$ in $C[0,1]$.